# Proving a particular linearly constructed set is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Take $C = \{q | q: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\}$ and let $W
= \mathbb{Z} \times C.$ Define multiplication on $W$ by
$(m,v)(n,t) = (m+n,s)$ where for each $z \in \mathbb{Z}, s(z)
= v(z-a) + t(z).$ I would like to prove that $W$ with this operation is a group.

Closure for this group is quite reasonable to prove, since
$$(m,a)(n,b) = (m+n,\phi),$$
and $\phi(x) = a(x-(m+n)) + b(x),$ and because $a$ maps to the integers and
$b$ maps to the integers, the sum of their outputs will also be an integer,
and so $\phi$ maps to the integers and hence $\phi \in C.$

However, I am having difficulty showing the identity element and finding the
inverse. I would imagine that identity would be $(0,e)$ where $e$ is the
identity mapping, but that hasn't seemed to work. Any recommendations on how
to go about this part of the problem?

Comment: What is the $a$ that appears in the definition of $s$ in the first paragraph?  Also, does $C$ contain all functions $q:\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, or are there restrictions on the kind of $q$ allowed?

Comment: You seem to be using a different rule for multiplication when you wrote ''$\phi(x)=a(x-(m+n)) + b(x)$". I would guess that "$a$" in the formula for $s$ should be "$n$", and likewise that this formula should be "$\phi(x) = a(x-n) + b(x)$".